# xampp on my machine does not enable me to send email through SMTP but it works on other pcs

Tags: email, smtp, xampp

I was just wondering why my xampp that I installed on my pc won't enable me to send emails through any Mailing APIs(PHPMailer, Swift, etc..)

It's a different case when I run my email-enabled project on other machines as it proceeds to send mail without any problem on the SMTP settings.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be 
established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0] in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer
\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:269 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer
\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(58): 
Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishSocketConnection() #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\vendor\swiftmailer\
swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): 
Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\vendor\
swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(65): 
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\function\email.php(48): Swift_Mailer-
```

> send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\function\functions.php(82): 
>       sendVerificationEmail('12313i@gm...', 'a2a7fe9dc66a3cf...') #5 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\login.php(1): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 
>       {main} thrown in
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\vendor\swiftmailer\
>       swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 269

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings?

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, 

edit: will post the error log